# Python Getters and Setters

Tags: python, class, properties, getter-setter

#### How should I access the class instance variables in my `roll` method?

Should I access `self._value` with `self._value` or use my setter by accessing with `self.value`? Same question for `self._sides`.

```
import random


class MSDie:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self._sides = sides
        self._value = 1

    @property
    def sides(self):
        return self._sides

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, number):
        self._value = number

    def roll(self):
        self._value = random.randrange(1, self.sides + 1)
```

So basically, should I create the `roll` method like this instead:

```
def roll(self):
    self.value = random.randrange(1, self.sides + 1)
```

Now I know how to do it correctly the conventional way of `get_value`/`set_value` but I am trying to learn how to create more pythonic classes.

Just out of curiosity, why doesn't `self.value(random.randrange(1, self.value + 1)` or `self.value(self, random.randrange(1, self.sides + 1)` access the `self._value` variable and change it?

Answer (score 4):

In your current implementation, the value-property is of no use. If you have a setter with, for example, additional checks, you have to decide, if `roll` needs the additional checks or not. If not sure, use `self.value`.

Comment: In what case WOULD be my value-property of use? I am just learning about these decorators.